# react-leaflet typeError when trying to render coordinates

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, react-leaflet

I'm working on a React project with Redux / thunk and I have this map from react-leaflet :

```
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, Circle } from "react-leaflet";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function Maps() {
    const user = useSelector((state: any) => state.userReducer.getUserById);
    const coords: [number, number] = [user ? user.latitude : 0, user ? user.longitude : 0];

    const fillBlueOptions = { fillColor: "blue" };
    const zone = 10000;

    return (
        <MapContainer className="maps" center={coords} zoom={10} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Circle center={coords} pathOptions={fillBlueOptions} radius={zone} />

            <Marker position={coords}>
                <Popup>Adress</Popup>
            </Marker>
        </MapContainer>
    );
}

export default Maps;
```

I get the coordinates of the user with an axios call :

```
export const getUserById = (id_user: number | string) => {
    return (dispatch: any) => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true));
        return axios
            .get(`users/getUserById/${id_user}`)
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch(isLoading(false));
                dispatch({ type: GET_USER_BY_ID, payload: res.data });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                dispatch(isLoading(false));
            });
    };
};
```

The dispatch is launched here when i click on this table :

```
<tbody>
  {users.slice(0, 20).map((item: any, index: number) => (
    <tr
        className="redirectUser"
        onClick={() => {
            history.push("/Utilisateurs");
            dispatch(getUserById(item.id));
        }}
        key={index}
    >
        <td>{item.id}</td>
        <td>
            {item.nom} {item.prenom}
            <br></br>Tcheker
        </td>
        <td>{item.email}</td>
        <td>18/10/1998</td>
        <td>{item.tel}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

When I try to display the map component on a user who has the coords, i have this error (or the map just show blank screen) :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined

Then if i go back in the history and re-click on the table, the map finally displays with no error.

When the user doesn't have any coords I get this error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lng' of null

I understand that the component seems to render before getting the datas, but even with a ternary operator that gives a hard-coded value in case of an undefined answer, the component doesn't render neither.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an async issue. The very nature of your coords variable looks to be non-blocking and hence the render is performed before the ternary can be performed.
Since coords is just a variable (and not state driven) it never re-renders.
If you could set the state at the time coords is calculated and then refer you're leaflet map to the variables in state, I think you could get it working.

Good luck,

Phil